# 1-dimensional nonlinear global minimization of kepler distance problem

Tags: optimization, rootfinding

I want to solve the problem to determine the next intersection of a Keplerian orbit with the Sphere of Influence of a celestial body to find the next intersection within one future period of the satellite orbit (the satellite and the celestial are both in confocal Keplerian orbits around a primary star or planet and this is just a patched conic approximation with no perturbations).

The general solution to this seems difficult, particularly for small synodic periods compared to the period of the satellite, so I'm confining myself to looking first at the problem of synodic periods that are near to the period of the satellite.  I'm also aware of the Minimal Orbital Intersection Distance (MOID) problem, but if I understand that correctly that wouldn't help me with the next-sphere-of-influence crossing question that I have here (and is also quite complicated itself in its solution).

I can setup the problem as a minimization of the relative distances between the two bodies and I have at least a piecewise continuously differentiable function.  I have a starting bracket which is the current time or start of the orbit patch and an ending time which is one period of the satellite.  But I may have several minima in the interval and I don't know how to bracket individual inflection points, and the minimum I want may be several minima from the start (and may not be the global minimum).  This makes it difficult to use algorithms like Brent's minimization algorithm / golden section search, or to attempt root finding of the derivative of the function.

Since I care about finding the first intersection with SOI what occurs to me is that I can start from the beginning and use a linesearch algorithm like (I think) Armijo backtracking and alternatively climb and descend the function around the orbit until I find the first minimum distance which is less than the SOI radius.  The resultant algorithm would look something like successive application of a 1-dimensional quadratic subproblem (a very lightweight 1-d SQP solver) applied repetitively to search the space.  Does this sound reasonable, or are there better approaches for this kind of problem?

Alternatively, if I'm way too far down this rabbit hole and there's easier ways to solve it please let me know...

I don't think that using an IVP/ODE solver with an event trigger will work since that has the same problem as root bracketing methods where you may skip roots that are too close together.  I'm also solving for the minimum approach distance and can then use that to backtrack and solve for the SOI intersection, so the SOI is only used to accept or reject a minimum and I'm not trying to solve for those crossings directly.

And to restate, it is important that this algorithm be fast and reliable in simple cases, bounded by the period of the satellite.  And I'm considering the case where the period of the satellite is much greater than the target celestial is out of scope (at some point I'll probably use some heuristics around the synodic period to choose a more global optimization approach vs. brute forcing to find the first SOI crossing).